# load php page page output into html div using jquery ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I want to render output of php page into html div.That means in php page has lot of jquery stuff.suppose i used current jquery ajax to load a php page.It missed to load jquery document ready stuff.

How can i do that?

Comment: Please explain a bit more about the php page.. What does it return?

Comment: This question is not clear enough! Only thing I understood is "I want to render output of php page into html div".

Comment: Are you really using symfony *and* cakephp together?

Comment: i used jquery highchart in php page.when i run that page in separate it is working fine. when i try to render that php page using jquery ajax. It is missed to load jquery stuff on the php page.so i dint get proper chart output.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to put the output of a php page to an html page using jquery and ajax. You may do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.php");
});
```

div1 is the div which is to be updated with the php content.
This link may help you.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here's is the short example. [jQuery API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**html**

```
 <div id="content"></div>
 <input type="button" id="btnLoad" value="Load" />
```

**jquery**

```
$("#btnLoad").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page1.php',
        success: function(data){
                 if(data != null) $("#content").text(data)
         }
     });
});
```

**page1.php**

```
<?php

  echo "This is the sample data to be printed for request from AJAX";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax `observe` method

**[cakephp ajax helper](http://www.cakephp.4uk.pl/)**

```
<?php echo $form->create( 'Post' ); ?>
<?php $titles = array( 1 => 'Tom', 2 => 'Dick', 3 => 'Harry' ); ?>  
<?php echo $form->input( 'title', array( 'options' => $titles ) ) ?>
<label for="something">This checkbox will be send (and it will trigger Ajax reqest)  </label>
<input id="something" type="checkbox" name='data[Post][something]' value='1' />
</form>

<?php
echo $ajax->observeForm( 'PostAddForm', 
    array(
        'url' => array( 'action' => 'edit' ),
        'complete' => 'alert(request.responseText)'
    ) 
); ?>
```